# Как в Android Studio быстро задать минимальный уровень API для XML-файлов (ресурсов)?

Tags: android-studio

Как в Android Studio быстро задать минимальный уровень API для XML-файлов (ресурсов)? Допустим, я создал XML-файл в папке drawable, не указав его минимальный уровень API, требуемый для использования Android-приложением (указать его можно было в окне New Resource File, выбрав в Available Qualifiers параметр Version и указав в поле Platform API level соответствующий минимальный уровень API). Как я могу быстренько его указать или поменять *не пересоздавая* XML-файл?

Answer (score 1):

Создайте папку с [квалификатором](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources?hl=ru) вида `v<номер_API>` и переместите туда свой XML-файл

```
res/layout-v18/mylayout.xml   (Android 4.3)
```

Comment: А есть другой способ, чтобы не лазить в папку каждый раз? (Путь к ней очень далёк `C:/...appdata...AndroidStudioProject...res/layout/...`)

Comment: @nick: В Android Studio отличный проводник, причем в разных режимах.

Comment: Как в Android Studio открыть проводник?

Comment: @nick: View -> Tool Windows -> Project или (ALT + 1)

Comment: Не структуру проекта, а **Проводник Windows** я имею ввиду, саму папку открыть. Мне же ведь Android Studio не даст создать, к примеру, папку "layout-v18", если в проекте уже существует папка "layout". Проверьте.

Comment: @nick: вверху окна вышеописанного выпадающий список. выберите Project. Далее до папки с ресурсами: - app - src - main - res. Все создается и удаляется

Comment: Правой кнопкой мыши на папке res - New - Directory. Вводите название.

Comment: Нет же, не создаётся ничего. Правой кнопкой мыши нажимаю на папку res, затем выбираю New -> Directory и ввожу `layout-v18` - ничего не создаётся. Просто ничего не происходит, только дерево папок скрывается.